# Code First Many References to class without a FK

Tags: performance, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

We are all familiar with the [3 types of Inheritance](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph) 
However we have the following situation which doesn't fit.

1) We have a Locations Class

```
public abstract class Location
{
    public decimal geoLat { get; set; }
    public decimal geoLng { get; set; }

    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }        
}
```

And we have a Quotes Class

```
public class Quote
{
    public int QuoteId {get;set;}
    public decimal Qty {get;set;}
    public decimal SubTotal {get;set;
    //etc
}
```

What we would like to do is have the attributes of many locations so that our MSSQL Schema looks like this.

Quote
--QuoteId
--SubTotal
--JobgeoLat
--JobgeoLng 
--JobAddress1
--JobAddress2
--JobCity
--JobState 
--JobZip
--BillinggeoLat
--BillinggeoLng 
--BillingAddress1
--BillingAddress2
--BillingCity
--BillingState 
--BillingZip
--ShippinggeoLat
--ShippinggeoLng 
--ShippingAddress1
--ShippingAddress2
--ShippingCity
--ShippingState 
--ShippingZip

In our application we want to access the location information like myQuote.Location.Address1, etc.

We could of course just create a Fk like Quote.JobLocation, Quote.BillingLocation with a separate locations table. However the performance of using such Fk's would be not ideal for many reasons.

We could also just add the columns in the Quotes table just like in my example (that's how its setup currently) but we want to use the Strongly types Quote.BillingLocation, Quote.JobLocation, etc.

**So the Question is, how can we achieve the Quote table structure (storing the Location attributes directly in the Quotes table) while also using Quote.JobLocation, etc.**

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you thought about making Location a ComplexType and adding the different location properties to Quote? This will put the different locations in the same table as Quotes.

Comment: @KellyEthridge
That sounds like it could work.
I'll let you know how it goes and get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding 
    [ComplexType]

to the Location class then adding 
    public Location JobLocation {get;set;}
    public Location ShippingLocation {get;set;}

generated the correct properties inside the Quotes table.

Thanks @KellyEthridge